# python - Convert Time series Events into on off pair

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, iterator

I have a single table of both Safety related alarm and normal equipment alarm. these alarm are getting logged. table looks like

```
Name                        record     Timestamp
S303R2_LS_STN_ATD_SENSOR_ERR    1   19-11-2020 06:22:53
S303R2_LS_STN_ATD_SENSOR_ERR1   1   19-11-2020 06:22:53
S303R2_LS_STN_ATD_SENSOR_ERR    0   19-11-2020 06:22:55
S303R2_LS_STN_ATD_SENSOR_ERR1   0   19-11-2020 06:22:55
S304R2_LS_STN_ATD_SENSOR_ERR    1   19-11-2020 07:05:28
S304R2_LS_STN_ATD_SENSOR_ERR    0   19-11-2020 07:05:30
```

For safety related tag; if record=0, alarm is on and record=1, alarm is off (condition1) for Normal equipment tag; if record=1, alarm is on and record=0, alarm is off (condition2)

what i am trying to get is

```
    Name                              intime                   outtime 
S303R2_LS_STN_ATD_SENSOR_ERR    19-11-2020 06:22:53   19-11-2020 06:22:55
S303R2_LS_STN_ATD_SENSOR_ERR1   19-11-2020 06:22:53   19-11-2020 06:22:55
S304R2_LS_STN_ATD_SENSOR_ERR    19-11-2020 07:05:28   19-11-2020 07:05:30
S302R1_LS_STN_ATD_SENSOR_ERR    19-11-2020 08:07:08   19-11-2020 08:07:15
```

i have a list of normal equipment tags. if this tag name is available in list, alarm on/off pair should be formed on condition 2 orelse alarm on/off should be based on condition 1.

note: this becomes tricky when the Equip is switched off and on. all the equip tag will gets initialized with value 0 and safety tag with 1.

attached data set link :https://drive.google.com/file/d/19NIm_WWJDqSOUDc3O5G9pFW2InsQ4GOT/view normal equip tag link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UFFT-m4j6xlzKVQk8qjjsrZuQj6jJwSG/view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are duplicates in `Name, record` pairs, so first is created helper column by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), then is used [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with remove helepr column and rename columns:

```
df['g'] = df.groupby(['Name','record']).cumcount()
df1 = (df.pivot(index=['Name', 'g'], columns='record',values='Timestamp')
         .rename(columns={0:'intime',1:'outtime'})
         .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
         .reset_index())
```

And last is swapped values in column by mask with [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) for test membership with `list`:

```
m = df1['Name'].isin(L)
df1.loc[m, ['intime','outtime']] = df1.loc[m, ['outtime','intime']].to_numpy()
```

---

```
print (df1)
record                           Name               intime  \
0        S302R1_LS_STN_ATD_SENSOR_ERR  19-11-2020 08:07:08   
1        S302R1_LS_STN_ATD_SENSOR_ERR  19-11-2020 08:07:19   
2           S302_INTI_RB2_WATER_ERROR  19-11-2020 08:57:08   
3           S302_INTI_RB2_WATER_ERROR  19-11-2020 08:58:00   
4        S303R2_LS_STN_ATD_SENSOR_ERR  19-11-2020 06:22:53   
5       S303R2_LS_STN_ATD_SENSOR_ERR1  19-11-2020 06:22:53   
6        S304R2_LS_STN_ATD_SENSOR_ERR  19-11-2020 07:05:28   
7        S315R1_LS_STN_ATD_SENSOR_ERR  19-11-2020 11:58:48   
8        S316R2_LS_STN_ATD_SENSOR_ERR  19-11-2020 11:45:32   
9        S317R2_LS_STN_ATD_SENSOR_ERR  19-11-2020 11:45:32   
10       S318R1_LS_STN_ATD_SENSOR_ERR  19-11-2020 11:58:48   

record              outtime  
0       19-11-2020 08:07:15  
1       19-11-2020 11:57:20  
2       19-11-2020 08:57:59  
3       19-11-2020 08:58:00  
4       19-11-2020 06:22:55  
5       19-11-2020 06:22:55  
6       19-11-2020 07:05:30  
7       19-11-2020 11:58:59  
8       19-11-2020 11:45:50  
9       19-11-2020 11:59:50  
10      19-11-2020 11:58:59
```

Comment: This works fine for this dataset but if use it for entire records it is returning me error.ValueError: Length of passed values is 110, index implies 2.

Comment: dataset  is big thats why i am unable to upload. thank you very much for reply. can you help in the code which i have pasted

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/19NIm_WWJDqSOUDc3O5G9pFW2InsQ4GOT/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UFFT-m4j6xlzKVQk8qjjsrZuQj6jJwSG/view?usp=sharing

Comment: when i run your code it is returning me this error after pivot "Length of passed values is 1406, index implies 2."

Comment: @Nandan - With data what are shared? Do you test only this data?

Comment: i have checked the output dataframe, output what we are getting is wrong...... reason we are mapping the Alarm in and out based on the "Name" and "g" columns. since data has intial garbage value of 0 upto 142 rows. it has taken those value as outtime for those records. this is the reason i am trying the above code mentiond in the question.                         these garbage will occur time to time. best way to avoid is first match outtime to the tag name and then match the max timestamp which is less the outime for the respective tagname as intime.

Comment: Expected output from that data https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GGc423AxNaXfBn3d_GGnXwv_2blMk-9X/view?usp=sharing

Comment: in df data set, row 1 ~ 143 rows whose value is 0 are garbage value. we cannot avoid those in realtime.

Comment: explained the logic in question added a image also. can you please check that

Comment: I try understand it and it seems you need iterate for each matched values from list and find `1` pair to `0` ? And if there is bunch of 1,0 then is necessary test by datetimes? What are possible combinations `0,1` pairs here? It seems need someiterate solution here (what should be bad for performance)

Comment: donot worry about performance, i need solution even if it takes time. i am not sure other option available for matching in and out time perfectly

Comment: @Nandan - ya, but now I am no idea how do it :(

Comment: @Nandan - In my opinion is possible create question only for one pair? And explain how match if datetime is greater, less ? Because with this I failed, how do it vectorize way (looks like `merge_asof` with 2 or more joins per same id). My second problem is iterate functions are more complicated, because need working with all states (here with gretaer, less datetimes), so not sure how do it. :(